# How to find text for a folder pattern using grep

Tags: grep, find

I have www folder with lots of php projects. Hidden somewhere is a script in a `/cli/` folder that I'm trying to find. If I use this in the www folder:

```
grep -R "mycode" */cli/*
```

It's only finding files in `projectname/cli/`

But the cli folder is in a subdirectory somewhere. So I need it to match `projectname/subdir/cli/` or `projectname/subdir/subdir/cli/` etc.

Answer (score 2):

See if your shell supports `shopt -s globstar` (or similar). You can then use `**/cli/` to match `cli` recursively.

Or, using `find`

```
find -type d -name 'cli' -exec grep -R 'mycode' {} +
```